# Svelte on:change runs too late

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a Svelte app with:

1. A dropdown that lets you choose a chart to view (pie chart / bar chart / calendar)
2. A panel of checkboxes with variables to include in the chart. (Different charts have different variables available)
3. A function that filters my data just for the selected variables, then passes that data to a chart.

Full code that you can run here:

```
<script>
  let rawData = {
    LevelTracker: [{ text: "headache" }, { text: "pain" }],
    EventType: [{ text: "coffee" }, { text: "aspirin" }],
    Event: [
      { time: 1500000000, text: "coffee" },
      { time: 1500030000, text: "aspirin" },
      { time: 1500230000, text: "coffee" },
      // etc....
    ],
    LevelChange: [
      { time: 1500000000, text: "headache", level: 2 },
      { time: 1500030000, text: "headache", level: 3 },
      { time: 1500230000, text: "pain", level: 2 },
      // etc....
    ],
  };

  $: availableLTs = rawData.LevelTracker.map((e) => e.text);
  $: availableETs = rawData.EventType.map((e) => e.text);

  let schemas = [
    {
      name: "byTimeOfDay",
      vars: [{ name: "X", et: true, lt: true }],
    },
    {
      name: "lagBarChart",
      vars: [
        { name: "X", min: 1, et: true, lt: false },
        { name: "Y", min: 1, max: 1, lt: true, et: true },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "calendar",
      vars: [{ name: "X", et: true, lt: true }],
    },
  ];
  let chartsMap = {};
  for (let schema of schemas) {
    chartsMap[schema.name] = schema;
  }
  //let selectedChart = "lagBarChart";
  //let selectedChart = "byTimeOfDay";
  let selectedChart = "calendar";

  function getInitSelectedVars(schemaVars) {
    let selection = {};
    for (let varSchema of schemaVars) {
      selection[varSchema.name] = { ets: [], lts: [] };
    }
    return selection;
  }

  function initSelectedVars() {
    console.log("in initSelectedVars");
    selectedVars = getInitSelectedVars(schemaVars);
  }

  function makeChartData({ selectedVars, rawData }) {
    console.log("in makeChartData");
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(selectedVars)) {
      // TODO: we filter rawData for just the selected vars, and return that data...
    }
  }

  // this will be passed to the chart component
  $: chartData = makeChartData({
    selectedVars,
    rawData,
  });

  $: schemaVars = chartsMap[selectedChart].vars;

  $: selectedVars = selectedVars || getInitSelectedVars(schemaVars);
</script>

<main>
  <h2>Select chart type</h2>
  <select bind:value={selectedChart} on:change={initSelectedVars}>
    {#each schemas as chart}
      <option value={chart.name}>
        {chart.name}
      </option>
    {/each}
  </select>

  <h2>Select your vars</h2>

  {#each schemaVars as schemaVar}
    <h3>
      {schemaVar.name}
    </h3>
    {#if schemaVar.lt}
      {#each availableLTs as ele}
        <div class="form-check">
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              class="form-check-input"
              bind:group={selectedVars[schemaVar.name].lts}
              value={ele}
            />
            {ele}
          </label>
        </div>
      {/each}
    {/if}
    {#if schemaVar.et}
      {#each availableETs as ele}
        <div class="form-check">
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              class="form-check-input"
              bind:group={selectedVars[schemaVar.name].ets}
              value={ele}
            />
            {ele}
          </label>
        </div>
      {/each}
    {/if}
  {/each}

  <!-- then we display the selected chart, like:
     <calendar {chartData} />
   -->
</main>

<style>
</style>
```

Each time the user changes the dropdown, we need to re-initialize `selectedVars` to a value that matches the current chart's schema.

For example, if calendar is selected we need to do:

`selectedVars = {X: {ets: [], lts: []}}`

But if barchart is selected, we need:

`selectedVars = {X: {ets: [], lts: []}, Y: {ets: [], lts: []}}`

I defined a function that does this, and put `on:change={initSelectedVars}` in the chart dropdown. However, each time I change the chart type from 'calendar' to 'bar chart', I still get an error in my `makeChartData`:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'lts' of undefined
    at Object.mount [as m] (Debug.svelte:101)
    at Object.mount [as m] (Debug.svelte:95)
    at Object.mount [as m] (Debug.svelte:109)
    at Object.update [as p] (Debug.svelte:90)
    at update (index.mjs:764)
    at flush (index.mjs:732)
```

I think that on:change function would only get run after `selectedVars` is changed, so it's too late.

Any suggestions? My code is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, the error occurs in the `makeChartData` function?
It might be this line: `bind:group={selectedVars[schemaVar.name].lts}`

I have not fully understand your code yet, but it should be possible to change the value of `selectedVars` to the desired value with reactive statements. So, I don't think you need a `on:change` handler.

Edit:
I think you want something like that: https://svelte.dev/repl/57d760278e0e4acfad536c1269bceba3?version=3.37.0